# axapta thread / animation

Tags: animation, multithreading, axapta, ax

i have a function which costs plenty of time.
this function is an sql-query called via odbc - not written in x++, since the functional range is insufficient.

while this operation is running, I want to show an animation on a form - defined in the aviFiles-macro.
trying to realize, several problems occur:

- the animation doesn't start prior the function has finished.
- using threads won't fulfill my hopes, since the odbc-settings are made on the server and i guess, the function is called on client-side.
- besides - how am i able to get the information that the treaded task has ended up?

could anyone give me a hint, how to

- play an animation on a form
- do something ( in background ) and go on playing the animation until the task to perform is finished
- stop the animation

coding this in exactly this order shows the behaviour mentioned above.

thanks in advance for hints and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [standard AotFind as an example](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Using_Timer):

- split the work in small pieces each
- piece should be executed at timer
  tick

Also, you can try not to use timer, but to call infolog.yield() as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

this could potentially be done in a very complicated way with call backs and delegates if your odbc is in a vs project...

but isn't the real solution to try to find a faster/more effective way to query your data?